# Matching an images with series of templates

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am working on an application that matches a photo that taken from the mobile phone camera and matches with a series of images that saved in a database. Following java code works fine to match 1 image with 1 template. Please help me to develop this program to match with several templates and return the best match. I am using android studio to develop the application.

Thank you

```
    import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;
    import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
    import org.bytedeco.javacpp.indexer.FloatIndexer;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;
//import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
//import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class TemplateMatching {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        footPrint(args);
    } //main method

         public static void footPrint(String[] args){
    //read in image default colors
    Mat sourceColor=imread("F:\\image_processing\\Foot_Print_Temp_Match\\img.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);//this image should captured by the camera
    Mat sourceGrey = new Mat(sourceColor.size(), CV_8UC1);
   cvtColor(sourceColor, sourceGrey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


   //load in template in grey 
   Mat template1 = imread("F:\\image_processing\\templ.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);//Template should load from the database



    //Size for the result image
   Size size = new Size(sourceGrey.cols()-template1.cols()+1, sourceGrey.rows()-template1.rows()+1);
   Mat result = new Mat(size, CV_32FC1);//32 bit floating point signed depth in one channel 

   matchTemplate(sourceGrey, template1, result, TM_CCORR_NORMED) ;//Template matching function




   DoublePointer minVal= new DoublePointer();
   DoublePointer maxVal= new DoublePointer();
   Point min = new Point();
   Point max = new Point();
   minMaxLoc(result, minVal, maxVal, min, max, null);
   rectangle(sourceColor,new Rect(max.x(),max.y(),template1.cols(),template1.rows()), randColor(), 2, 0, 0);

   imshow("Original marked", sourceColor);
   imshow("Template", template1);

   waitKey(0);
   destroyAllWindows();


}
 public static Scalar randColor(){
   int b,g,r;
   b= ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 255 + 1);
   g= ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 255 + 1);
   r= ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 255 + 1);
   return new Scalar (b,g,r,0);
}

public static List<Point> getPointsFromMatAboveThreshold(Mat m, float t){
   List<Point> matches = new ArrayList<Point>();
   FloatIndexer indexer = m.createIndexer();
   for (int y = 0; y < m.rows(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < m.cols(); x++) {
           if (indexer.get(y,x)>t) {
          System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y +") = "+ indexer.get(y,x));
          matches.add(new Point(x, y));
      }
     }
   }
   return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[i have an application that basically does this.](https://github.com/mavriksc/overcomp)

Look at MatchingService and OpenCVUtils.
basically it should match a template, record the score and match the next template. keep list of scores associated to the template that made that score. then just get the max score.

```
public static float matchScore(Mat src,Mat tmp){

    Size size = new Size(src.cols()-tmp.cols()+1, src.rows()-tmp.rows()+1);
    Mat result = new Mat(size, CV_32FC1);
    matchTemplate(src, tmp, result, TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    DoublePointer minVal= new DoublePointer();
    DoublePointer maxVal= new DoublePointer();
    Point min = new Point();
    Point max = new Point();
    FloatIndexer fi = result.createIndexer();
    minMaxLoc(result, minVal, maxVal, min, max, null);      
    return fi.get(max.y(),max.x());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a great help. I'll go through your application. Thanks again.